# Console Log for 3rd Party Windows Application

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to build an app that can be used in Rasbian (Raspberry Pi Linux OS).  There is currently an .exe version available.  I would like to run the program in windows and see a console of the command structure currently in use so that I can duplicate for Linux app.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you clarify what you mean by command structure?  Do you mean decompile the program so you can see what the code is that it's running?  (Also, as written this question is not a good fit for SO; please read the how to ask a question to see examples of better questions that are a bit more focused)

Comment: THANK YOU.  That is the term I was looking for(I think).  Basically, I have an .exe application.  I want to build the same app essentially in python.  That app reads information from a USB device to check firmware.  So, I want to see what the program is doing in terms of code.  Does that make more sense?  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: So the issue with your question is that the answer is that there do exist tools that can take an exe and decompile (or at least disassemble) it... but there are  lot of issues (the most obvious being that most commercial applications explicitly ban doing this as part of the EULA) and as mentioned, this is not the sort of question SO is well suited for